# Is Tensorflow positional encoding wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I was checking this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#the_embedding_and_positional_encoding_layer and I saw this positional encoding function:

```
def positional_encoding(length, depth):
  depth = depth/2

  positions = np.arange(length)[:, np.newaxis]     # (seq, 1)
  depths = np.arange(depth)[np.newaxis, :]/depth   # (1, depth)

  angle_rates = 1 / (10000**depths)         # (1, depth)
  angle_rads = positions * angle_rates      # (pos, depth)

  pos_encoding = np.concatenate(
      [np.sin(angle_rads), np.cos(angle_rads)],
      axis=-1) 

  return tf.cast(pos_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)
```

However, that concatenation will append the cosine after the sine, instead of alternating them as asked in the paper:
[image]

infact plotting it shows:
[image]

instead something like:

```
def positional_encoding(len, token_size):
    depth = tf.range(token_size/2, dtype=tf.float32) * 2 / token_size
    divisor = 10000 ** depth
    position = tf.range(len, dtype=tf.float32)
    argument = (position[:,None] / divisor[None, :])[...,None]
    pre_alternation = tf.concat((tf.math.sin(argument), tf.math.cos(argument)), axis=-1)
    return tf.reshape(pre_alternation, (len,token_size))
```

shows something like this:
[image]

what am i missing?

Comment: The order of sine and cosine does not matter, as long as it captures positional information.

Comment: @coder00 ok so the only wrong thing is that they are claiming to implement that function, where instead they are using another one, just "as good", but not equal

Comment: Yes, not sure why they define it so.